# PHP returns incorrect HTML code ignoring some tags

Tags: php, html

I have the below code to display content from a database. The while loop is supposed to display data in a table row. The output is different: the data from the database are displayed before the table. The while seems to run and ignore the html tags, and then run again and ignore the variables.

PHP Code:

```
// Instantiate database
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

// List transactions without bundles
$query = "SELECT * FROM stock_trx WHERE bundleId IS NULL";
$statement =  $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$n = $statement->rowCount();

if($n > 0){

    echo "<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Select</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Ticker</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Currency</th>
            </tr>    
        </thead>
        <tbody>";

    // Retrieve table content
    while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        // Extract row
        extract($row);

        echo "<tr>".$id."</tr>";
        echo "<tr>".$date."</tr>";
        echo "<tr>".$type."</tr>";
        echo "<tr>".$qty."</tr>";
        echo "<tr>".$ticker."</tr>";
        echo "<tr>".$amount."</tr>";
        echo "<tr>".$currency."</tr>";

    }

    echo "</tbody></table>";
} else {
    echo "No transaction";
}
```

HTML output:

```
<html>
<body>

12020-05-13 00:00:00BUYTEST1000022020-05-19 00:00:00SELTEST1200032020-05-24 00:00:00DIVTEST250<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Select</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Ticker</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Currency</th>
            </tr>    
        </thead>
        <tbody><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body></html>
```

Thank you

Comment: where is the `td` tag ?

Comment: In the `tr` inside the `tbody` you are missing the `<td>` tags. Browsers then try to fix it which gives the result you are getting

Answer (score 2):

You need rows `<tr>` and cells `<td>` inside the row:

```
while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    // Extract row
    extract($row);

    echo "<tr>";   // start row
    echo "<td>".$id."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$date."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$type."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$qty."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$ticker."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$amount."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$currency."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";  // end row
}
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

Contrary to the other answer I would either do this, since you're using double-quotes:

```
echo "<tr>";   // start row
echo "<td>$id</td>";
// etc...
```

Or combine into one, maybe even one line:

```
echo "
<tr>
<td>$id</td>
<td>$date</td>
<td>$type</td>
<td>$qty</td>
<td>$ticker</td>
<td>$amount</td>
<td>$currency</td>
</tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

While some others have mentioned that you need TD tags, I'd just like to point out some weirder PHP-type things that may or may not help you now / in the future.

Your statement can be rewritten

```
<?php
while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
    // Extract row
    extract($row);?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $id; ?>?</td>
      <td><?php echo $date; ?>?</td>
      <td><?php echo $type; ?>?</td>
      <td><?php echo $qty; ?>?</td>
      <td><?php echo $ticker; ?>?</td>
      <td><?php echo $amount; ?>?</td>
      <td><?php echo $currency; ?>?</td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

This uses some lesser seen formats for using HTML in PHP files, but it should work never-the-less (tested locally with the PHP 7.4 CLI). Some people prefer it to having to use `echo` to output all of the HTML, but you do still have to have a bunch of echo statements to print the variables.

To reiterate, there's nothing wrong with any of the other answers, I just feel that in cases like this where you are using a bunch of HTML with PHP that this sort of notation can be a bit easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

As some people replied, the below tag is missing:

```
<td>
```